# Why is my site requesting (unsuccessfully) a font from an unrelated site

Tags: css, security, debugging, firefox, request

In my deployed website, I'm seeing this in the logs in Firefox:

[image]

My site has nothing to do with abc.net.au (although that is a site I browse often).

I've grepped my deployed code to be sure, and there are definitely no references anywhere that I can see that would be causing it to try to load these font files.

Clicking on the source code link doesn't reveal anything useful (just the index.html page).

Perhaps it's some kind of plugin going wrong?

How can I diagnose and fix the cause of these inappropriate font requests?

Comment: My first thought is that these are stray entries from when you were using abc.net, not fresh ones from your current site. Does the same thing happen in other browsers?

Comment: I've updated my answer: this looks like a known bug in the current version of Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is make sure that the lines come from content requested from your website. You have 2 ways to do that:

1. Create a [new Firefox profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles), start it, close all the tabs and just leave 1 blank tab. Open the logs, clear them and then open your website. If the font line is not here, then it might have been a bogus log line.
2. On your original Firefox or new profile, open a new tab. Open up the [Network Monitoring tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) and then open your page. Look for the font entry in the network request. Unfortunately, it's not yet possible (see [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=821610)) to break on specific network requests in the Firefox dev tools.

From there, I would go and check the source code depending on my findings. Keep us posted!

**Update**: this sounds like [bug 1420680](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1420680).

Comment: Thank you for finding the bug! Nice to know it's not some rogue plugin or something.